# Why does reading S3 bucket return Access Denied, even with root credentials (from CLI)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Versions:

```
aws-cli/2.7.32 Python/3.9.11 Darwin/22.6.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off
```

There are many stackoverflow articles on `Access Denied` responses triggered by access-attempts to an S3 Bucket.  Here, my question concerns root-access privileges.

In my case, I provision root CLI credentials (ie, Access Key / Secret created from AWS root account).  Then I define these credentials in the usual place:

```
$ cat ~/.aws/credentials
[list-s3-bucket]
output=json
aws_access_key_id=XXX
aws_secret_access_key=YYY
```

where `XXX` and `YYY` are obfuscated.

Then I run this CLI command to access the S3 bucket `my-stuff`:

```
$ aws --profile list-s3-bucket s3 ls s3://my-stuff/

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

The error suggests a permissions issue.

QUESTION: how come root CLI access credentials are not good enough to see the bucket `my-stuff`?

There are many articles that talk about bucket-specific permissions, attaching the right policy to the accessing user, and so on.  But to my thinking, none of those are relevant.  This is a CLI command with root privileges.  Why can't it see `my-stuff`?

The natural sequel to this question is:  Since root cannot see `my-stuff`, then how can I ever gain visibility to `my-stuff`?

One passing thought is that `my-stuff` does not exist.  So I tried the exact same CLI command for a non-existent bucket:

```
$ aws --profile list-s3-bucket s3 ls s3://my-stuff-does-not-exist/

An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The specified bucket does not exist
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://repost.aws/questions/QUlGVziWVIQbazBJENCSWuGA/can-resources-be-made-hidden-from-root-user. According to that, there are four places you need to look at: SCP, Resource based policy, Permissions boundary and Session policy.

Comment: Run `aws --profile list-s3-bucket sts get-caller-identity` to confirm you are using the credentials you think you are using. If that's OK, then I would guess that you have mis-typed the bucket name or it's in a different AWS account to the root user. If you create an IAM user with S3 permissions and create and use that IAM user's associated credentials, does it work?

Comment: Is `my-stuff` a placeholder for the bucket name you're trying to access, or the literal name you're attempting to access?  If it's the literal name, you won't have access, no doubt such a simple name has already been reserved and used by another account.

Comment: @AnonCoward:  are you saying used by another account that we manage, or another AWS account managed by someone else?  If it's another account that we manage, then why wouldn't our AWS root account still be able to access that?

Comment: If you're literally using `my-stuff`, then it's another AWS account, unless you have a very old account that somehow got `my-stuff` before anyone else.  AWS S3 bucket names are a global (not even region specific) namespace, shared by all AWS accounts.

Comment: @AnonCoward:  I believe yours is the correct answer.  The inaccessible bucket is not `my-stuff`, but `pem-files`, and I had no idea bucket names/paths were globally unique.  Print your response as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: That's also what I mentioned in "I would guess that you have mis-typed the bucket name or it's in a different AWS account to the root user" but @AnonCoward's comment obviously got you thinking in the right direction so credit where due.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on [AWS Bucket Naming guidelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucketnamingrules.html):

> Bucket names must be unique across all AWS accounts in all the AWS Regions [...]

In other words, bucket names are in a global namespace that all accounts share.

Given the scale of AWS and S3, for very simple names like `my-bucket` or `basic-files`, it's *very* likely a given bucket name is already used, and you in fact do not have cross account access to connect to the bucket, so the Access Denied error is expected.